# Checking querystring values in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, query-string

```
http://localhost/?area=characters&name=Michal+Stroganof



$result = mysql_query("SELECT * from players WHERE name = '$_GET[name]'");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    echo "Name: " .$row['name']. "<br>";
    echo "Level: " .$row['level']. "<br>";

}
```

This is all code of my characters.php

If the get variable "name" is not included in the URL i want to show a search form that searches the table players. How would I do this?

Comment: Read on about SQL injections: http://unixwiz.net/techtips/sql-injection.html

Comment: It is probably the case that your example is just for simplicity's sake, but if it is live code please research SQL Injection and Prepared Statements.

Comment: use an input function to filter input and avoid sql injection type problems, as well as escaping the input when it gets put into the sql, as jheddings mentions above!  never trust user data.

Comment: Err, as jheddings mentions below, that is.

Answer (score 9):

Do you mean just to change your SQL string like so?

```
$sql = 'SELECT * from players';
if (isset($_GET['name'])) {
    $safename = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['name']);
    $sql .= " WHERE name='$safename'";
}
$result = mysql_query($sql);
```

Be sure to sanitize your SQL!

Answer (score 5):

Use [`isset()`](http://php.net/isset):

```
if (isset($_GET['name'])) {
    // your above code
} else {
    // display form        
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Quick and dirty:

```
<?php
if (!isset($_GET['name']))
{
    echo  '<form action="'. $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] .'" method="GET">'
         .'<input type="text" name="name" />'
         .'</form>';
}
else
{
    // your current code that queries your database here
}
?>
```